# Show and format array elements in jQueryUI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

In my app there is an option to select documents by checking the checkboxes. Then if user clicks on submit button he gets a confirmation box which shows all the documents which he has selected for deletion. I store all the selected docs in an array. Now I want to represent the document list in a well formatted manner. Like

```
Warning: Below mentioned documents will be deleted, review them and click OK to proceed.

 1. Document 1
 2. Document 2
 3. Document 3
 n. Document n
```

So my confirmation box should look like above. Since this can't be done using default `confirm` box so I used `jQuery UI dialog` but there also I'm unable to format it. Can someone help me with the formating? Is there any other option available to show a list in confirm box?

[What I've tried](http://jsfiddle.net/nM3Zc/995/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str="";
for(var i=0;i<arrayis.length;i++){
str+=(i+1)+")"+arrayis[i]+"<br/>";
}


ConfirmDialog("Below mentioned documents will be deleted, review them and click OK to proceed?"+"<br/>"+str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nM3Zc/1003/

Answer (score 0):

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/nM3Zc/1007/)**

```
var arrayis = new Array();
arrayis = ['document1', 'document2', 'document3'];
var string='Below mentioned documents will be deleted, review them and click OK to proceed <br>';
for(var i=0;i<arrayis.length;i++){
  string+=(i+1)+")"+arrayis[i]+"<br/>";
}
ConfirmDialog(string);

function ConfirmDialog(message){

    $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                    .html('<div>'+message+'</div>')
                    .dialog({
                        modal: true, title: 'Warning', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                        width: '500px', resizable: false,
                        buttons: {
                            OK: function () {
                                // $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');                                
                                // $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            Cancel: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it gets hits for the issue at hand, which ends up being simple, and was happening to me today.

I was adding my string of formatted text to my dialog div with .text() instead of .html()
Wrong way:

```
$( "#dialog-message-div" ).text(str);
```

This caused it to escape all HTML characters...removing formatting, but worse showing a non-technical user "technical" things...HTML!

Right way:
Simply changed the .text() to .html() and it works like a charm.

```
$( "#dialog-message-div" ).html(str);
```

Taken from the jQueryUI example index.html bundled with the download.

```
<html lang="us">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
   <link href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(function() {      
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         width: 400,
         resizable: false,
         buttons: [
            {
               text: "Ok",
               click: function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
            },
            {
               text: "Cancel",
               click: function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
            }
         ]
      });
      // Link to open the dialog
      $( "#dialog-link" ).click(function( event ) {
         $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
         var str = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipisicing elit</b>, sed do eiusmod <i>tempor</i><br /><br /><br />incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br />Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>";
         event.preventDefault();
         //wrong way
         //$( "#dialog" ).text(str);

         $( "#dialog" ).html(str);
      });
   });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="dialog-link">Dialog Button</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```